Custom image popup changing behaviour
My KivyMD app from an SQLite database displays a binary blob image for which I created a dialog content class with MDBoxLayout as parent. The database has two images for a particular index, a 300x310px output.jpg file, the other a 320x400px picture.jpg file.
When I changed the image to picture.jpg the image pops up but when I close it, scroll to another index and open the popup, the image doesn't change and it shows the last one that opened. If I close it and wait a minute and open it again, the right image shows.
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacting: "2sp"

    Image:
        id: image
        source: root.photo_name

class Content(MDBoxLayout):
    photo_name = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.photo_name = "picture.jpg"

class MainApp(MDApp, RecycleView):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       
    ##### OTHER CODE ########

    ### Popup function ###
    @staticmethod
    def view_popup():
        popup = Popup(title="FULL PHOTOGRAPH", title_align="center", content=Content(),
                      size_hint=(.85, .8))

        popup.open()

How can changing the image file with the same code bring different results? Can the pixel size cause a delay in the class changing its instance? I tried MDDialog instead of the popup using type="custom" and content_cls=Content(). Still same result. I changed the source in the Content class from root.photo_name to app.photo_name defined in MainApp class as photo_name = StringProperty("picture.jpg"). Same result.
